# Dialog box showing only for the first time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a confirmation dialog.
If I click the `click` button, the dialog box will appear and then click 'cancel' button in that dialog box, so that it closes.

Now, the issue is on second time onwards, If I click the `click` button the dialog box is not showing up.

// App.js

```js
import ConfirmationDialog from "./ConfirmationDialog";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [confirm, setConfirm] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = () => {
    setConfirm(true);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>click</button>
      {confirm && <ConfirmationDialog />}
    </>
  );
}
```

// ConfirmationDialog.js

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import DialogTitle from "@mui/material/DialogTitle";
import DialogContent from "@mui/material/DialogContent";
import DialogActions from "@mui/material/DialogActions";
import Dialog from "@mui/material/Dialog";

function ConfirmationDialogRaw(props) {
  const { onClose, open, ...other } = props;
  const handleCancel = () => {
    onClose();
  };

  const handleOk = () => {
    onClose();
  };

  return (
    <Dialog
      sx={{ "& .MuiDialog-paper": { width: "80%", maxHeight: 435 } }}
      maxWidth="xs"
      open={open}
      {...other}
    >
      <DialogTitle>Title</DialogTitle>
      <DialogContent dividers>
        <Button autoFocus onClick={handleCancel}>
          Cancel
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={handleOk}>Ok</Button>
      </DialogContent>
      <DialogActions></DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
  );
}

function ConfirmationDialog() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(true); // on first click 'open' is true

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false); // on 'cancel', sets 'open' to false
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: "100%", maxWidth: 360, bgcolor: "background.paper" }}>
      <ConfirmationDialogRaw
        id="confirmationId"
        keepMounted
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
export default ConfirmationDialog;
```

I think, after I click "cancel", `open` state is set to `false` and it's not becoming `true` when I click 'click` button next time. How to solve this?

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dialog-box-not-showing-sofl-sljqmm) Demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major problem that I think is creeping in is because you are trying to maintain 2 different states for showing the modal and rendering it.

I have tried to fix the same for you by uplifting the ConfirmationDialog component's internal state to the parent component. You can check the sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/fix-dialog-box-not-showing-ib7s3e?file=/App.js)